# automatic data transfer in android through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have 2 android devices

I need one of them to automatically get the other device's data (battery strength , signal , contact list , etc.. ) after they bind

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it but for this purpose you have to write the code as Stub-Skeleton (Client - Server) where one listens and one processes.
Let me know if you have any other question.

Latest android mobile devices provide [Wifi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)  feature i believe it will be bit more faster than the blue tooth.

P.S: Both Bluetooth 4.0 and Wi-Fi Direct use the 802.11 networking standard to reach their maximum speeds. but bluetooth 4 device-to-device transfer speeds of up to **25mbps** while wifi direct promises till 250mpbs. Choice is yours; 
Happy Coding !

Comment: thank you but are you familiar with any API's of android or opensource libraries to perform this kind of task or should I implement the OBEX protocol through NDK or something myself?

Comment: Well android provides the complete Api Reference, like [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

you can find apis for any thing like this way.